# ShadowJs Returning <pre> and <code> tags by default

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, markdown, showdown

I am using ShadowJs with Handlebars templating to process markdown that is being used in my record text field, but I have a persistent error that happens where the text is processed and converted to markdown with `<pre><code></code></pre>` wrapping all of the text that was inputed in the field rather than just the text with the markdown-specific code wrapping. Is there a reason why this is happening? Maybe the result of my JS setup?

**activity-feed.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var converter = new showdown.Converter();
    var markdownInput = document.getElementById('discovery-text');
    console.log('Pre conversion' + markdownInput.innerHTML);

    var convertTextAreaToMarkdown = function(){
        var markdownText = markdownInput.innerHTML;
        var html = converter.makeHtml(markdownText);

        console.log(html);

        markdownInput.innerHTML = html;

        console.log(markdownInput);
    };

    convertTextAreaToMarkdown();
};
```

Console.logs:

**line 4:**

```
Pre conversion
                                ##h2
```

**line 10:**

`<pre><code>                            ##h2 
</code></pre>`

```
line 14:

<div id=​"discovery-text">​<pre>​<code>​                            ##h2 
​</code>​</pre>​</div>​
```

**view file:**

```
<div id="discovery-text">
                {{{discovery.discovery}}}
            </div>
```

Comment: As per standard Markdown syntax, anything indented by 4 or more spaces (or one or more tabs) is parsed as a code block (wrapped in `<pre><code>` tags). If you have content that it not supposed to be in a code block, then make sure it is not indented.

Comment: @Waylan thanks for the response. It seems like an issue with the way that my strings are being stored, which is causing the indentation and now makes sense why I am seeing code blocks. Thank you!